# Error while reading webpage

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, html-parsing

A part of my app includes going to a webpage and parsing its text to get a Bible Verse of the Day. For the main app, I have tossed the code into an ASyncTask and it works great, but I am trying to get it so that I can do the same thing in a Broadcast Receiver and am having issues. I have copied the code from the doInBackground() method and set up the following method. The only changes I have made were to directly save the gathered data when it was found as opposed to storing them in temporary variables to be handled in the onPostExecute() method.

```
public void getVOTD() {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website = new URI("http://verseoftheday.com");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        //Read line by line, looking for the sepcific lines on the webpage
        while((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(l + nl);

            if(l.contains("og:title")) {
                ref.setText(l.substring(55, l.length() - 4));
                Toast.makeText(context, ref.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(l.contains("og:description")) {
                String des = l.substring(43,l.length() - 4);
                des = des.replaceAll("&quot;", "\"");
                des = des.replaceAll("&#039;", "'");
                des = des.replaceAll("&amp;#8212;", "--");
                ver.setText(des);
                Toast.makeText(context, ver.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        in.close();             
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ref.setText("Error");
        ver.setText(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        if(in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this method throws an exception as soon as it tries to read a line. The exception has no message, but I get the following stack trace:

```
05-14 13:54:19.288: W/System.err(23789): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
0

5-14 13:54:19.288: W/System.err(23789):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at com.caseybrooks.scripturememory.views.VOTDCard.getVOTD(VOTDCard.java:85)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at com.caseybrooks.scripturememory.views.VOTDCard.initialize(VOTDCard.java:74)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at com.caseybrooks.scripturememory.views.VOTDCard.<init>(VOTDCard.java:50)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at com.caseybrooks.scripturememory.fragments.DashboardFragment.initialize(DashboardFragment.java:76)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at com.caseybrooks.scripturememory.fragments.DashboardFragment.onCreateView(DashboardFragment.java:50)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5114)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
05-14 13:54:19.298: W/System.err(23789):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 13:54:19.368: D/libEGL(23789): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
05-14 13:54:19.368: D/libEGL(23789): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
05-14 13:54:19.368: D/libEGL(23789): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
05-14 13:54:19.378: I/Adreno200-EGL(23789): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:269>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_VANILLA.04.02.02.60.051_msm8960_JB_VANILLA_CL2997615_release_AU (CL2997615)
05-14 13:54:19.378: I/Adreno200-EGL(23789): Build Date: 04/11/13 Thu
05-14 13:54:19.378: I/Adreno200-EGL(23789): Local Branch: 
05-14 13:54:19.378: I/Adreno200-EGL(23789): Remote Branch: quic/mako_jb_mr1
05-14 13:54:19.378: I/Adreno200-EGL(23789): Local Patches: NONE
05-14 13:54:19.378: I/Adreno200-EGL(23789): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_VANILLA.04.02.02.60.051 +  NOTHING
05-14 13:54:19.398: E/(23789): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
05-14 13:54:19.398: E/(23789): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
05-14 13:54:19.398: E/(23789): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
05-14 
13:54:19.398: D/OpenGLRenderer(23789): Enabling debug mode 0
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are trying to do the networking from the main thread. That is the reason you got this Exception:

[NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

==> stick to your first idea and keep doing that from an AsyncTask to keep your app responsive. This counts also for BroadcastReceivers, [see this guide here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#Avoiding):

> The specific constraint on BroadcastReceiver execution time emphasizes what broadcast receivers are meant to do: small, discrete amounts of work in the background such as saving a setting or registering a Notification. So as with other methods called in the UI thread, applications should avoid potentially long-running operations or calculations in a broadcast receiver.